# Scientific plotter that works with dark themes

Tags: themes, kde, colors, scidavis

I have to plot and analyze some data, and the programs I know are Scidavis and Qtiplot. The problem is that both do not work on dark themes (white text on white, black text on black), and in the preferences there is no way of telling them not to use the (KDE) theme colors. In fact, there is no way of setting default colors at all, apart from unselected text in tables.

Are there updated versions or forks which handle colors better?

Comment: May be, it is more convenient to report a bug about this.